# Processing.org Applications Sometimes Crash With No Indication

Tags: error-handling, crash, processing

I have two applications that I have written using the Processing.org language. They are pretty basic, make regularly scheduled calls to the internet, and display data.

Sometimes, after these programs have been running for a while, they will crash for an unknown reason. The real issue at this point is that the application does not signal the crash in any way. The screen sits there as if it is waiting for the next bit of data - which normally could be several minutes, so it does not seem odd that the screen is blank.

Is there a way to cause a Processing.org application to shut down or show an error message when any fatal error occurs?

Thank You.

Comment: It's hard to guess what the issue might with no code or detailed explanations. Would it be possible that errors aren't probably handled and if requests to server timeout or something the app freezes (just a wild guess) ? Also you might want to have a look for crash logs/reports for hints

Comment: The errors are pretty rare, sometimes has to run for hours before encountered. I figure I will eventually weed out the cause, but this is why I am asking if there is "a way to cause the application to shutdown / show a message when ANY fatal error occurs."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing programs are Java programs.  As George mentions in his comment, it's impossible to tell from this question what might be throwing the Exception that causes the program to crash.

However, if the Exception is generated from within the main program loop (Processing's draw() function), you can wrap that in a try-catch block and handle the exception in a visible way, e.g.:

```
void draw () {
    try {
        // your code here...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // display the Exception message on-screen
    }
}
```

You might need to also set a flag that tells the program to only draw that Exception message to the screen and not continue running the offending code.

Since the Exception could be thrown from somewhere in the program *other* than the draw() loop, you won't necessarily catch it here.  Your best bet, then, is to look in logs.  If you're on OSX, try Console.app (in /Applications/Utilities) to see if your program spat out anything to stderr.  I don't know a Windows equivalent but there should be logs somewhere.

In short, "what George said".  But hopefully this answer elaborates on that in a useful way.